# Find associated Keys based on Values - Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have two separate `lists`; `List<datetime>` & `List<string>` respectively. For ex:

- {1/1/2000, A},
- {1/2/2000, B},
- {1/3/2000, A},
- {5/10/2004, A}

I would like to get `List<datetime>` when the `string`= "A".
I did create a `dictionary<List<datetime>,string>` but then it's finding `keys` based on `values`.

Comment: Actually, you'd use the dictionary to find `values` based on `keys`.  a `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>` may be what you meant to use. That these values are in two lists makes them unrelated until you do something like that to determine otherwise.

Comment: did you try Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>?

Comment: The string should be your `Key`, since that is the object you are searching on.  The `Key` is the first generic argument.  You should reverse your generic arguments in the `Dictionary`, as @Jim Suggested.

Comment: correct @ymz. How would i handle that if I create dict<string,List<datetime>>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? The assumption is the lists are matched by index in list.

```
var list1 = new List<DateTime> {new DateTime(2000,1,1), new DateTime(2000, 1, 2), new DateTime(2000, 1, 3), new DateTime(2004, 5, 10) };
var list2 = new List<string> {"A", "B" , "A" , "A" };

var output = list1.Zip(list2, (time, str) => new {time, str})
    .Where(o => o.str == "A") // Change to the string you want to filter
    .Select(o => o.time)
    .ToList();

foreach (var dateTime in output) {
    Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Using dictionary makes it complicated in this specific scenario. Thanks @Student222

Comment: @user7157732 You are welcome! Glad to hear that it helped! : )

Comment: @user7157732 This particular example works because the two lists are the same size and the index match for both the key and the value. You really want to reconsider using a `Dictionary`

Comment: hi @LuisLavieri I added a comment in your solution. could you advice?

Answer (score 3):

You want to keep track of dates based on a particular key. So, what you want to do is this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>
```

This way. You can have a list of values for a particular string.

e.g. `A -> 1/1/2017, 1/2/2017, 1/3/2017`

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();

//populate your dictionary
dictionary.Add("cat", new List<DateTime>{DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)});

if (dictionary.ContainsKey("cat"))
{
    var dates = dictionary["cat"];
    //now you have access to those dates
}
```

Comment: The dates are random in the List<datetime>... How would this handle that?

Comment: I don't know the logic behind populating your list of datetimes. Also, you should not care about it. It's an example. You just care about the key and how to access those random dates.

Comment: assume there are two columns of data; one with date and another with an event(string) on those dates.  Since these are two separate dataset, I need to somehow hook them together to be able to say; find all the dates on which this "specific event" occurred. In your solution, not only I need to add "cat" but need to first check if "cat" occurred on that date.. @LuisLavieri  Can you advice?

Comment: How many events are we talking about? Is it a one to one relationship between a date and a event? Are they coming from a database? They belong to the same table with the same id?

Comment: Let's say up to 5 events at a particular date. Yes, in the same table in the database for the same id. DATES would be same, time may differ for a  particular event.

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing something like below, basically reverse your key and value.

```
  var dateTimeByStringLookup = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>()
                {
                    {"a", new List<DateTime>() {new DateTime(2017, 1, 2), new DateTime(2017, 1, 3)}}
                };
                var datetimes = new List<DateTime>();
                dateTimeByStringLookup.TryGetValue("a", out datetimes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<DataTime>> kvp in dictionary)
{
    if(kvp.Value == listImLookingFor)
    {
       var key = kvp.Key;
    }
}
```